# elaboration on the equation of directional derivative that lead to steepest gradient descent

Tags: calculus-of-variations, image-processing

I am reading the book

> Ian Goodfellow and Yoshua Bengio and Aaron Courville, *[Deep Learning](http://www.deeplearningbook.org)*, MIT Press, 2016.

I am reaching to the point about directional derivative. Given the $u$ as the unit vector and the gradient $\nabla_xf(x)$
In the book, the equation is to minimize the loss function which is as below:
$$
\min_{u, {u^T} u =1}{u^T}\nabla_xf(x)
=\min_{u, {u^T} u=1}\|u\|{_2}\|\nabla_xf(x)\|{_2}\cos\Theta
$$
where $\Theta$ is the angle between $u$ and the gradient $\nabla_xf(x)$.
From my understanding, in visualization, the length of $u$ is minimum when it is further away from the gradient, on which the vector $u$ is projected. Thus, that's why there is $\cos\Theta$. But I'm not quite confident in my thought and I am not sure what the $_2$ are about.
Hence, I appreciate anyone can help elaborating from the first line to the second line.
Thank you in advance for any feeback!

Comment: The equation $u^T\nabla f(x)=\|u\| \|\nabla f(x)\| \cos(\Theta)$ has nothing to do with optimization. It is rather the definition of the angle. Anyway, this question is not research level and would be more suitable for MathStackExchange.